# Two (or more) looks, with one set of content

Tags: plugins, themes, clone-site

I'd like to set up a pair of sites (`red` and `blue`) with different looks (backgrounds, header images), but the same content (pages, text, embedded media, etc.) And I'm trying to minimise the effort keeping them synced once set up.

e.g., the two sites might have a root URL like: http://example.com/red and http://example.com/blue. The URLs http://example.com/red/about and http://example.com/blue/about would both show the same about page, ideally edited in only one instance and auto-magically updated in the other.

Ideally I'd like to be able to have users flip from one to the other like a multilingual site.

I've thought about mirroring `red` to `blue` and then customise `blue`; but I expect to have to updated `red` in the future and I don't want to have to redo the mirror/customisation each time.

Have I missed a convenient way/plugin for accomplishing this kind of situation?
Is there a better way? Or am I going to be maintaining content on two sites with different looks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something pretty simmilar once where I had 2 websites that shared most of their content and had differing color schemes. Here's how I would approach this challenge

Use Multisite and child themes in the following way:

- **Website 1**: This holds the content and acts as the main theme (e.g. Red). This is just a regular WordPress site — no funky stuff going on here.
- **Website 2**: This installation switches to blog 1 (`<?php switch_to_blog( $website_1_id ); ?>`) whenever it queries data and then uses a child theme to apply the blue styling.

[Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) will give you the ability to have different URL's for the two sites and still query for content between the sites.

You can even use domain mapping to have completely different url's like my-red-website.com and my-green-website.com

[Child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) will make it much easier to maintain the two themes in the future, as all of your functionality lives in the main theme (website 1). Your child theme (website 2) inherits everything from the main theme and builds on top of that with custom CSS and PHP. Whenever you add new functionality to website 1 it automatically cascades down to website 2 as well.

I'm not sure that there aren't any gotcha's with this approach, but if I was in your shoes this is the path I'd try first.